# SuiteAnalytics doesn't show tables on the left hand side panel

Tags: sql, netsuite, datagrip

[image: screenshot]

I'm using a JDBC driver downloaded from NetSuite to connect to NetSuite2.com.
I am not able to see any tables on the left hand side, but I am able to run queries...
I have already selected show all databases / schemas in the options.
Some other info: this seems to be an issue only when I'm using DataGrip. No issues if I use DBVisualizer.
Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Try to do "Force refresh" in the context menu of the database.

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov thanks for the comment. I tried, but it didn't work...